# how to run python script as a start up application via command line in ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04

I have python script that execute android emulator
how I can execute this python script on startup?

the problem is that I open ssh session execute the android emulator and when I close the ssh session the emulator stop

Comment: Running something at start-up is different from keeping something running after you log out from SSH. [On question 1](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=running+program+at+start+up+ubuntu) and [on question 2](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=keep+process+running+after+log+out+ssh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meant to say you want a script to be executed every time you logged in to a machine.  If I understood your requirement correctly, then have a look at the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)